# Form action url using present url

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I m in a flsk project with python.
I need to define my from action in order to add in the url symbol variable.

My template url is like this:
http://xxxxxxx/sell1/AAPL

AAPL is symbol variable value

see1.html code is:

```
{% block main %}
    <form action="/sell1/AAPL" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="stock" name="symbol" value="{{ stocks }}">

            , owned
            <text id="nbr" name="amountbefore">
                 {{ nbr }}
            </text>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input min="1" autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="amount" placeholder="Amount" type="number">
        </div>
        <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sell</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

app.py code is:

```
@app.route("/sell1/<string:stock>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def sell1(stock):
    """Sell shares of stock"""

    # User reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
    if request.method == "POST":
        # collect relevant informations

        amount = int(request.form.get("amount"))
        symbol = request.form.get("symbol")
        price = lookup(symbol)["price"]
        value = round(price * float(amount))

        # Update stocks table
        amount_before = db.execute("SELECT amount FROM stocks WHERE user_id = :user AND symbol = :symbol",
                                   symbol=symbol, user=session["user_id"])[0]['amount']
        amount_after = amount_before - amount

        # delete stock from table if we sold every unit we had
        if amount_after == 0:
            db.execute("DELETE FROM stocks WHERE user_id = :user AND symbol = :symbol",
                       symbol=symbol, user=session["user_id"])

        # stop the transaction if the user does not have enough stocks
        elif amount_after < 0:
            return apology("That's more than the stocks you own")

        # otherwise update with new value
        else:
            db.execute("UPDATE stocks SET amount = :amount WHERE user_id = :user AND symbol = :symbol",
                       symbol=symbol, user=session["user_id"], amount=amount_after)

        # calculate and update user's cash
        cash = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = :user",
                          user=session["user_id"])[0]['cash']
        cash_after = cash + price * float(amount)

        db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = :cash WHERE id = :user",
                   cash=cash_after, user=session["user_id"])

        # Update history table
        db.execute("INSERT INTO transactions(user_id, symbol, amount, value) VALUES (:user, :symbol, :amount, :value)",
                   user=session["user_id"], symbol=symbol, amount=-amount, value=value)

        # Redirect user to home page with success message
        flash("Sold!")
        return redirect("/")

    # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    else:

        # Add Symbol

        # query database with the transactions history
        rows = db.execute("SELECT symbol, amount FROM stocks WHERE (user_id = :user AND symbol = :stock)",
                          user=session["user_id"], stock=stock)

        Nbr = rows[0]['amount']
        return render_template("sell1.html", stocks=stock, nbr=Nbr)
```

My goal is to have a code that change in sell1.html form action url to suit with symbol variable (AAPL in my example, but could be something else.)

the symbol is at the end of url, or in input text : id=stock (line 4 of hthe code)

Could someone can help me ?
Maybe a javascript code ? (but I m not good at this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try this and it works

```
    <form id="actionform"  method="post" onsubmit="get_stock_quote()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="stock" name="symbol" value="{{ stocks }}">

            , owned
            <text id="nbr" name="amountbefore">
                 {{ nbr }}
            </text>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input min="1" autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="amount" placeholder="Amount" type="number">
        </div>
        <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sell</button>
    </form>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function get_stock_quote()
    {
        var form = document.getElementById('actionform')
        var symbol = document.getElementById('symbol').value
        var action_src = "/sell1/" + symbol

        form.action = action_src;
    }
</script>
```